# A couple have 9 children, half of children are boys, how?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

My friend asked me the puzzle,

> 1. A couple have 9 children (none of them were adopted)
> 2. Each child must be either a boy or a girl
> 3. Half of that couple’s children are boys
>
> **How that can be possible?**

I failed to answer. So, how it is possible?

Comment: I believe this question is more lateral-thinking than logical deduction

Comment: Maybe they have adopted someone

Comment: None of them were adopted. Updated the description. @defectedWBC

Answer (score 5):

If

> at least 5 of the children are boys

then technically

> half of the children are boys... plus more, but the question doesn't state "*only* half".

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit of [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), but

> if both partners of the couple have children from an earlier marriage, let's say one has four and the other one has three, and they have two children together, then they have nine children in total, but that couple's children are only two, and one of them can be a boy and the other a girl.

Comment: None of the children were adopted. Updated the post.

Comment: I can't come up with a better answer, but this seems to defy point #1 - in this scenario, the couple has 2 children, not 9. Under this interpretation, we'd have to say the couple has 9 children, but 7 of them aren't their children, which is a contradiction - it relies on a self-inconsistent definition of what it means to be "somebody's child"..

Comment: Let's see if there is any answer

Comment: I'm sure one of the more creative minds here will come up with a better explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

> **All of the children are boys.**
>  
>
>   Half of the children are boys. The other half are, too.

Comment: That's essentially what I said in [my earlier answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97881/25966). :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can say:

> If the couple's firstborn is now an adult, you could no longer technically classify them as a child.
> Then, if 4 out of the remaining 8 "not-yet adults"(or children) are boys, then we meet the necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer,**

> The couple have even number of child more than 9 and half of them are boys

**Explanation,**

> If I say, I have 5 apples with me, then it's also true that, I have 4 apples with me, I have 3 apples with me and so on. **Thus, the couple have 9 children does not violate that the couple have more children when we take other premises to be true.**